# Как в Laravel Model отсеить дубли по полю 'test', что бы выводились только уникальные записи?

Tags: laravel

Как в Laravel Model отсеить дубли по полю 'test', что бы выводились только уникальные записи?
Пытался через Model::distinct('test')->get();
Не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Model::distinct()->groupBy('test')->get();
```